# Setup pptpd and tunnel through it

Tags: linux, centos, windows-7, pptpd

I want to setup pptpd on my linux server and tunnel through it like if I were tunneling through ssh. Is it possible to setup the vpn connection to be a local proxy that way I can choose what programs connect using it?

Answer (score 0):

If your "programs" support to specify the bind ip/interface, then you can choose when to go through VPN and when not. Also you should remove defaultroute from the VPN connection.

Regards

Comment: Unless you are doing source-routing, choosing an IP/interface to bind to, does not change the route used.

Comment: True. I forgot about that ...